# share data between two angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am angular 2.0 beginner and wondered if anyone can help me with passing data from one component to another.

My project is made up of three parts, a login window component, a table component and center component to handle routing. when the users log in in the login component, a http.post request will be sent to server to authenticate. if the credentials are authentic, a json containing users' information will be returned from the server . The page will also be routed to a table component showing the name of this user and his/her other info.

these two component are on the same page using  router-outlet.

Here is my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'td-app',

  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent

        },{
            path: 'table',
            component: TableComponent
        },{
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/login',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
        ])
    ],
```

Here is the data I wanna pass into another component. the **postUser** method is doing http.post and an json string will return. I wanna pass this json data to my next component. I was thinking using promise to make sure the data is assigned to the variable **userInfoPack** and then pass **userInfoPack** to next component's template.

login.component.ts:

```
 postUser(body: User): Promise<any>{

      return Promise.resolve( this.getUser(body))
                    .then(response => this.userInfoPack = response );   
  }

  getUser(body: User){

    this.userJson =  JSON.stringify(body);

    this.loginservice.postUser(this.userJson)
                    .subscribe(response => this.userInfo= response);

    return this.userInfo; //subscribe method ends here

  }
```

this is the template I wanna pass data into. I want to use **@input**

to pass the data but I dont know how.

table.component.ts:

```
template: `
        <h2>Hi, {{userInfoPack}}</h2>
          `
```

### Please help me with this, thank you!

Also is there any way that we can route the page to another component, since i use a button to route the page and send http.post request to authenticate account at the same time.

```
<button type= "button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
(click)= "postUser(user)" style=" position: relative;
left: 90%;" routerLink= '/whoison'>
    Login
</button>
```

I don't how to route the component after the credentials are sent and authenticated. (can we use **routeLink** in a function instead of a directive? )

Any suggestion or advice will be helpful, thank you!

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thank you Gunter!  I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi, Gunter, in the link you gave me, it's talking about parents and children communication, but in my case it's sibling communication. Should I make the login component the parent, but if that is the case, the login window won't disappear after user log in. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Seems you didn't read past the first paragraph :p Components added by the router are not siblings in regard to component communication in Angular2.

Comment: Oops, you are right :) . Also do you have any suggestions on calling functions to route? In my project, the http.post and routing are done using the same button. but i wanna only route to another component after the http.post request is completed. Is there anyway I can make a callback function executing routing after the post request is done?

Comment: Sorry, I encountered the same problem again.. the methods provided on the link requires me to put another component's selector(or customized directive) in the template, but i don't wanna do that since I don't want these two components showing at the same time on the same page....

Comment: I don't think a shared service requires you to put a component anywhere.

Comment: So in the link, the way they pass data is like calling child compoent directive in parent component template: e.g. <child-component [hero]="hero"></child-component>  here hero is the data they wanna pass in.  is there a way we dont call the child component directive in the parents component's template/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to do this.

We can use **local storage** if you only want to share **string** variable.

e.g.

app.component.ts

```
localStorage.set('name', 'yeehaah');
```

other.component.ts

```
var name = localStorage.get('name');
```

This way, you can access the name variable 'yeehaah' in 'other.component' from 'app.component'

Welcome to elaborate on this!

Answer (score 1):

Best solution would be create a sharing service to maintain your data. I had a similar challenge in one of my Angular application. Created a sharingService directive/class and injected/imported into both controller. Now due to singleton nature of services once you update data from one controller it could be fetched/read from other controller. 
A good example with Angular 2 :

Bootstrapp your shared service into your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ SharedDataService ]);
```

Do not add it again in providers attribute of your components. This way you will have a single instance of the service for the whole application.

```
@Component({
  selector : "selectorName",
  // providers : [SharedDataService ], //---- not needed
  template : `I'm MyComponent  and shared data is: {{data}}`,
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
  (...)
}
```

Comment: but do we need to inject the data in the template? e.g. <child-component [hero]="hero"></child-component>

Comment: not necessary or I would say depends on your use case. If you want to pass data from A controller to B Controller where A was first initialized and B later.